LLMs and Christianity
There have been recent questions related to LLMs:

What are the official positions of the various denominations on LLMs?
What is an overview of positions on whether there is something wrong with letting an LLM "play the role of God"?

One of the claims made is

the current and future generations will use this technology as a primary technology.

My question is what uses might Christians use LLMs for, from a theological standpoint? Not asking what/how might a Christian use LLMs in their job or day to day. What uses might LLMs provide for Christians for Christian/religious purposes? Is there a use?
I don't believe LLMs will be used for creating new scripture. LLMs are not the best at citing sources, but it could summarize beliefs (though I feel like this would generally be used for learning about other denominations/beliefs not one's own)

I've used catholic.chat a lot in prepping confirmation classes, not too handy in answering questions here. But you can get a gist for things and it does a great job of telling you what's in the catechism and what isn't.

@PeterTurner just curious is it better than simple search engine for finding catechisms?

yeah, it's way better. it's basically the first one I've ever found that doesn't suck.  I've gotta think if they take the G out of GPT they'll make a lot more friends.
